Show non conjugacy of flows of linear systems
We have the two linear systems:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{x}_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 27x_1 - 68x_2 \\ 10x_1- 25x_2 \end{pmatrix} \small(1)
$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} \dot{y}_1 \\ \dot{y}_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix} \small (2)$$
System (1) gives us two eigenvalues $\lambda = 1 \pm 2i$ and (2) trivially gives us $\lambda = 1$ with multiplicity 2.
Both systems have an equilibrium at the origin (0,0) and an unstable behaviour.
We have tried to show conjugacy with some rotational matrix but it hasn't been possible, so then we thought that the systems might not be topologically conjugate near the origin.
The question that arises is then:
Is there any way to prove non-conjugacy of systems?
Ideas:
The main idea that we have is that if we had something (B) that holds based on the assumption that two systems are topologically locally conjugate around the origin (A), then proving that this doesn't hold (not B) would conclude that they are not conjugate (not A), but we haven't found anything related.
Our main source of truth is the book of Perko.
Any advice is helpful, thank you!

These two systems are topologically equivalent, so there is no way you can prove the opposite.

@Artem Could you please argue on that? How would you prove it?

There is a general result that says that two linear vector fields are equivalent if they have the same number of eigenvalues with the same signs of real parts. You may try to prove it in whole generality, but it is not an easy exercise. See Arnold's textbook on ODE. You can try to build the equivalence directly in your example, but this is also not exactly trivial (you will never be able to present a diffeomorphism, it does not exists, only a homeomorphism). You can find an example in, if I remember correctly, Applied Bifurcation Theory by Kuznetsov (third edition).
